# Emacs crashing on OSX, no crash log file

Tags: helm, projectile, crash

My Emacs started to crash a lot without modifying `.emacs` or installing anything new.

I can replicate the steps (using Helm, Projectile) by this:

1. `helm-projectile`
2. then I enter a query quickly and hit backspace
3. I have a crash.

According to [GNU Emacs Crash page](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Crashing.html) I should find a crash log but I am unable to find it in OSX. The OSX crash dump itself is useless for me. I would like to know what in my `.emacs` is wrong or which plug-in is failing?

Comment: Perhaps you can find one in `~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports`? Or if you have XCode installed, you could attach `gdb` to the process and get at backtrace.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I can find crash report in DiagnosticReports but its the same information OSX presents to me. I cant decypher anything from it :)

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen also I have newer OSX maybe so I have LLDB but cant attach it. Could you provide some information ?

Comment: Sorry, I have never used LLDB, but there is some information to be had by running `lldb --help`. You can easily run a fresh emacs under LLDB by running `lldb -- /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -Q` (assuming this is where it's at, and assuming you want the `-Q` flag for emacs). Then once lldb starts and you have authorized it to do its job, you type `run`. Then trigger the crash in emacs, and come back to lldb to get a backtrace by using the `bt` command. (Note that lldb also has a `help` command. Use it.)

Comment: I might add that if your emacs executable is stripped, you are not likely to get much out of the backtrace. Good luck.